# ARcore Augmented images with 3D object interaction

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore

I want to build a digital catelog application
where i detect the image in a catelogue and place a 3D object on it
This can be achieved by ARcore Augmented images.
what i need is When i click/touch the 3D object I need to show some information and videos
For this particular task i need some SDK options
without Vuforia can this be achieved using ARCore+Unity or Android OpenCV or any other.

Comment: What SDK options do you mean you can achieve with Vuforia but you can't with ARCore?

Answer (score 0):

This requires a lot of work from creating animations and layers to define colliders and controlling with backend code.

First you create the animations and animation controllers, then add colliders to the hot spots where you want to click on the object (e.g. touch the door to open), then map each  collider click event to fire a specific animation.

actually it is better to follow a tutorial that shows the animating basics, then it will be easy to combine with AR project,

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/animation